# SQL Server: convert rows to columns without pivot and grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

Originally I have a SQL Server table like below:

```
Result  Type    Type Order  Type Value
--------------------------------------
KM1    Color    1             Blue
KM1    Shape    2             Square
KM1    Size     3             10
KM3    Color    1             Blue
KM3    Shape    2             Square
KM3    Size     3             10
KM2    Color    1             Red
KM2    Shape    2             Round
KM2    Size     3             20
KM2    Color    1             Blue
KM2    Shape    2             Square
KM2    Size     3             10
KM2    Color    1             Blue
KM2    Shape    2             Round
KM2    Size     3             10
```

and my expected result should be like

```
Color   Shape   Size    Result
-------------------------------------
Blue    Square   10     KM1, KM3, KM2
Red     Round    20     KM2
Blue    Round    10     KM2
```

Could this be done? I don't think the pivot will help as I have same result for the multiple combination of values.

Comment: The title might have been the same on the proposed duplicate.  The question is very different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is two levels of aggregation.  The first is to describe each result.  The second is to get the keys together.  So:

```
with t as (
      select result,
             max(case when type = 'Color' then value end) as color,
             max(case when type = 'Size' then value end) as size,
             max(case when type = 'Shape' then value end) as shape
      from t
      group by result
     )
select color, size, shape,
       stuff( (select ',' + t2.result
               from t t2
               where t2.color = t.color and t2.size = t.size and t2.shape = t.shape
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 1, '') as keys
from (select distinct color, size, shape
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can this be done dynamically? Like the header color, size, shape can vary for other result like color, width, height. How can handle in that case?

Comment: @GopalB . . . I would suggest that you Google "SQL Server dynamic pivot".